# Why does BufferedWriter refuse to write a file?

Tags: java

I am making a snake game for my class project in school. Everything was fine until I looked at my code. It produced no errors when I "build" it but returns NumberFormatException.

P.S I am only a 1st year college student. Please be gentle

```
    private void checkScore() throws IOException{
        try{
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("scores.txt"));
    if(score > Integer.parseInt(highest)){
                highest = Integer.toString(score);
            } else {
            }
                }catch(IOException e){
    }
    bw.write(score);

    bw.close();
    }
```

The result I want from this is that when a player ends the game, the score would get recorded. If its a high score then it would be recorded in a scores.txt file. But my BufferedWriter refuses to write a file which results to the error mentioned.

Comment: Maybe you should be checking for the possibility of the exception instead of silently ignoring it.  You should also also put some debug statements in you code to ensure the that logic you expect to be executed is getting executed. And, you really should be making use of [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: You can use the debugger, especially on your else statement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `highest` has not a valid integer value when you do `Integer.parseInt(highest)`. Use debug options to see which value contains and fix that problem.